# How can i edit a follow path constraint with the graph editor?

Tags: bezier-curves, constraints, keyframes, path, graph-editor

I made a follow path constrait with a curve, does it already have a linear interpolation so i can edit it on graph editor? i need the linear interpolation.

Comment: Are you using animate path button, or the offset parameter?

Answer (score 7):

[image]

When you use a follow path constraint the movement and select **Animate Path**, there are no keyframes, the movement is determined by a couple of parameters:

1-The number of **Frames** on the path animation and **Evaluation Time** of the curve the object is parented to. The default is to move the object through the complete length of the path in 100 frames.

[image]

2- A **Generator Modifier** in in the evaluation time that can be displayed the Graph Editor. The movement starting at 0 and increasing linerarly one unit in X (time) and one unit in (Evaluation time value)

[image]

So to determine the speed at which the object will travel through the path there are two options:

A.- Change the number of frames on the curves path animation parameter. Less frames will make the object travel faster across the path. More frames will make it go slower.

[image]

B.- Altering the slope of the curve on the generator. A steeper line will make the movement faster, a flatter will slow it down.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you select the curve, you should be able to animate the evaluation time, in the graph editor =)

[image]

Comment: As long as you don't click the animate path button in the curve constraint...

Answer (score 6):

If you use the Follow Path constraint but **do not** activate the Animate Path option. You can move your object using the **Offset** value, note that depending on your path's direction you might need negative values. That will create keyframes for the object's movement.

[image]

Then on the Graph Editor you can set the interpolation you want by pressing <kbd>T</kbd> (or Key->Interpolation Type) and selecting Linear.

[image]