# How to pause camera along animated path

Tags: camera, keyframes

I have a camera parented to an animated curve (CTRL+P). I want to slow and stop the camera's speed at various points along the curve. The curve has a generator modifier (which is why I cannot keyframe the Evaluation Time in the Object Data tab)  and I'm using the Restrict Frame Range parameters to delay the start of the path animation to frame 60. When I set the Out parameter for the frame at which I want the camera to pause movement, it jumps back to the beginning of the curve. Is there a way to pause movement along a curve while still using Restrict Frame Range parameters to delay the start of the path animation or must I "hard keyframe" each camera location? P[image]lease say there's an easier way!

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21041/change-start-time-of-camera-following-a-path/21046#21046 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23835/how-can-i-edit-a-follow-path-constraint-with-the-graph-editor/23839#23839

Comment: so you could just delete the Generator and put some keyframes on the Evaluation Time of the curve, or as Cegaton said, give a Follow Path constraint to your camera

Answer (score 2):

Parenting the camera to a path gives you very little control on the camera motion. Use a follow path constraint instead, and animate the offset value.

Answer (score 0):

Use camera keyframes instead of follow path. Use LocRotScale.