# Ease camera acceleration which follows a path

Tags: animation, camera, path

I let a camera follow a round path which also tracks an empty (see reference). There is no problem in animating this, however I want the camera to start moving slowly and generate more speed and also to come to a halt slowly (ease in & out). But when I take a look in the graph editor there is no curve to edit.

[image: 01]

[image: 02]

Edit:

Also if I choose the curve there is no graph to adjust.

[image]

Comment: Don't parent the camera to the curve, use a Follow path constraint. Read also: [How can I edit a follow path constraint with the graph editor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23835) and [change the start time of a camera following a path](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21041/change-start-time-of-camera-following-a-path/21046#21046)

Comment: The camera isn’t parented to the path. Also I used the follow path and tracking constraint.

Comment: Read through the suggested links and look  also at this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23384/1853

Comment: @cegaton
blender.stackexchange.com/a/23384/1853 is very useful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you've used either a 'Follow Path' constraint or parented the camera to your path with the 'Follow Path' option, the keyframes you're looking for are on the path itself, not the camera.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately not, see my edited post above.