# Animation keyframes from file

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes

I'm trying to do an animation starting from some data I collected. The data is stored in a single txt file which looks like pretty much as

```json
o1 x y t
o1 x y t
...
o2 x y t
...
```

where `o1` and `o2` are two object identifiers, `x` and `y` are cartesian coordinates on the ground plane, and `t` is the timestamp of the observations.

My aim is to render the movement of the two objects while preserving time information.

I already know how to read in the text file and create the paths. I'm using this function

```py
def create_curve(coords_list, name):
    crv = bpy.data.curves.new('crv', 'CURVE')
    crv.dimensions = '3D'
    spline = crv.splines.new(type='NURBS')
    spline.points.add(len(coords_list) - 1)
    for p, new_co in zip(spline.points, coords_list):
        p.co = (new_co + [1.0])
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new(f'path_{name}', crv)
    bpy.data.scenes[0].collection.objects.link(obj)
```

At this point I import the two object models and follow [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23835/how-can-i-edit-a-follow-path-constraint-with-the-graph-editor) to make them follow the paths.

My problem is that I cannot find an automatic way to link timestamps from the file to the animation keyframes. Is there a way to synchronise the two?

Comment: This will be a lot easier if you simply keyframe location values to define the motion path. _eg_ set the location `ob1.location = (x, y, 0)` and keyframe it `ob1.keyframe_insert('location', frame=f(t))`  where `f` converts `t` to frames.  (or build animation fcurve directly from data)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @batFINGER, I'll give it a try.
My problem though is that I then have to adjust the paths (scale, location) as the data from file is not perfect. By assigning keyframes directly to the objects this is not possible anymore